# Build release app cannot receive push on client with Proguard Android Kotlin with SignalR

Tags: android, kotlin, signalr, proguard

I have issue when build release app with SignalR cannot receive push data from api.
but when run debug that working fine. So how can we do with this case because my project sign Proguard build release app.

build.gradle

```
   implementation files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
   implementation files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
```

Waiting Receive Data:

```
hubProxy?.on("ReceiveDataPush", SubscriptionHandler1 { data: String ->
    val aaaa = data
    hubConnection?.stop()
    hubConnection?.disconnect()
}, String::class.java)
```

I see when:

- SUCCESS (Run on bebug):

```
    D/SIGNALR_LOG_POS: HubConnection - Invoking event: onReceive with arguments ["......The same....."]
    D/SIGNALR_LOG_POS: serverSentEvents - Trigger onData: {"id":"1", "name":"abc"}
```

-ERROR (Build enable progurd):

```
    D/SIGNALR_LOG_POS: HubConnection - Invoking event: onReceive with arguments ["......The same....."]
    D/SIGNALR_LOG_POS: HubConnection - Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(boolean)' on a null object reference
    D/SIGNALR_LOG_POS: serverSentEvents - Trigger onData: {}
```

Thanks for you help.

I expected error with build release app cannot receive push on client with **SignalR Proguard **Android Kotlin with this case:
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException